# A nonconcave function where all local maxima are global minima - name?

Tags: convex-analysis, non-convex-optimization

Is there a special name for the functions in which all the local maxima are also the global maxima?

E.g. a sinusoidal wave is nonconcave and it has multiple maxima. But each of the maxima are global maxima.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The sine curve is concave on some intervals and convex on others. Maybe you mean by "nonconcave" only that it isn't concave at every point of its domain?

Comment: yes, it isn't concave at every point of its domain.